# vscode - redhat-developer/vscode-java - multi root workspace - java.project.sourcePaths

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How to configure `java.project.sourcePaths` in a multi root workspace?

I tried the obvious options - doesnt seem to work.

Using `Add folder to Java source path` just adds the folderpath directly without handling multi root.

Edit :

Classpath Configuration page has a dropdown to choose project folder. But lists only one folder.

[image: classpath config]

Comment: As for now, VS Code Java does not support configurations in multi root folder scope, it only supports workspace level. So you can set it in workspace level but that configuration will be applied to all the workspace folders in your workspace.

Comment: @ShengChen ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

source path takes an array as an argument. you can configure them like below:-

```
{ 
   "java.project.sourcePaths": ["/src1 path", "/src2 path"] 
}
```

Comment: this works fine in a single root folder workspace. my query is for a multi root workspace